# react + redux make an infinite loop

Tags: rest, api, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a issue with react + redux. I am trying to get my first redux base app working but I get an infinite loop.

My demo app contains only one button and when I click on that I would like to perform a  rest api call. But when I open my app url in the web browser then I can see in the console log that the rest api is called automatically in an infinite loop and I do not why. Could you please help me?

**This is the console log:**

```
--- start --------------------
dispatching Object { type="waiting-for-response",  waitingForResponse=true,  hasError=false}
next state Object { waitingForResponse=true,  hasError=false}
----- end --------------------
posting...
waiting-for-response
--- start --------------------
dispatching Object { type="waiting-for-response",  waitingForResponse=true,  hasError=false}
next state Object { waitingForResponse=true,  hasError=false}
----- end --------------------
...
show-cards
> --- start --------------------
dispatching Object { type="show-cards",  waitingForResponse=false,  hasError=false}
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
next state Object { waitingForResponse=false,  hasError=false}
----- end ----------------------
```

**request-response log:**

```
GET /demo/ > 200 OK
GET bootstrap.min.css > 200 OK
GET bootstrap-theme.min.css > 200 OK
GET bundle.js > 200 OK
GET time.jsontest.com > 200 OK
GET time.jsontest.com > 200 OK
GET time.jsontest.com > 200 OK
...
```

And the source:

**App.js**

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
    console.group(action.type);
    console.log('--- start --------------------');
    console.log('dispatching', action);
    let result = next(action);
    console.log('next state', store.getState());
    console.log('--- end ----------------------');
    console.groupEnd(action.type);
    return result
};

let store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));

ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Card/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Card.js**

```
class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.waitingForResponse ? <p>fetching...</p> : null}
                {this.props.hasError ? <p>service is not available, try it later</p> : null}
                <Button onClick={this.props.getCards('param1', 'param2')}>Button</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        waitingForResponse: state.waitingForResponse,
        hasError: state.hasError
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getCards: (param1, param2) => dispatch(performPost(param1, param2))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Card)
```

**CardActionType.js**

```
export default {
    WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE: 'waiting-for-response',
    COMMUNICATION_ERROR: 'communication-error',
    SHOW_CARDS: 'show-cards'
}
```

**CardAction.js**

```
const waitingForResponse = () => {
    return {
        type: CardActionType.WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE,
        waitingForResponse: true,
        hasError: false
    }
};

const communicationError = () => {
    return {
        type: CardActionType.COMMUNICATION_ERROR,
        waitingForResponse: false,
        hasError: true
    }
};

const showCard = () => {
    return {
        type: CardActionType.SHOW_CARDS,
        waitingForResponse: false,
        hasError: false
    }
};

export function performPost(param1, param2) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log("posting...");
        dispatch(waitingForResponse());

        axios({
            baseURL: 'http://time.jsontest.com/',
            method: 'get'
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('request performed successfully');
                dispatch(showCard());
            })
            .catch((response) => {
                console.log('communication error');
                dispatch(communicationError());
            });
    }
}
```

**Reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
    waitingForResponse: false,
    hasError: false
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        waitingForResponse: action.waitingForResponse,
        hasError: action.hasError
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your render method of CardAction you don't provide a callback function to the onClick handler, instead you execute the action-creator. You should call the action-creator within a function, so you should write it as a fat arrow function.

What happens is that the action-creator is called on every render, and the render function keeps getting called because you keep updating the redux-store.

```
class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.waitingForResponse ? <p>fetching...</p> : null}
                {this.props.hasError ? <p>service is not available, try it later</p> : null}
                <Button onClick={() => this.props.getCards('param1', 'param2')}>Button</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So to clarify, use:

`<Button onClick={() => this.props.getCards('param1', 'param2')}>Button</Button>`

instead of:

`<Button onClick={this.props.getCards('param1', 'param2')}>Button</Button>`

Comment: Glad to help :)